# Why does Scala type inference fail here?

Tags: scala, overloading, type-inference, overload-resolution

I have [this class](http://jamesgolick.com/2010/2/8/monkey-patching-single-responsibility-principle-and-scala-implicits.html) in Scala:

```
object Util {
  class Tapper[A](tapMe: A) {
    def tap(f: A => Unit): A = {
      f(tapMe)
      tapMe
    }

    def tap(fs: (A => Unit)*): A = {
      fs.foreach(_(tapMe))
      tapMe
    }
  }

  implicit def tapper[A](toTap: A): Tapper[A] = new Tapper(toTap)
}
```

Now,

```
"aaa".tap(_.trim)
```

doesn't compile, giving the error

> error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.trim)

Why isn't the type inferred as `String`? From the error it seems that the implicit conversion does fire (otherwise the error would be along the lines of "`tap` is not a member of class `String`"). And it seems the conversion must be to `Tapper[String]`, which means the type of the argument is `String => Unit` (or `(String => Unit)*`).

The interesting thing is that if I comment out *either* of `tap` definitions, then it does compile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **6.26.3 Overloading Resolution**
>
> One first determines the set of
>   functions that is potentially
>   applicable based on the shape of the
>   arguments
>
> ...
>
> If there is precisely one alternative
>   in B, that alternative is chosen.
>
> Otherwise, let S1, . . . , Sm be the
>   vector of types obtained by typing
>   each argument with an undefined
>   expected type.

Both overloads of `tap` are potentially applicable (based on the 'shape' of the arguments, which accounts for the arity and type constructors FunctionN).

So the typer proceeds as it would with:

```
val x = _.trim
```

and fails.

A smarter algorithm could take the least upper bound of the corresponding parameter type of each alternative, and use this as the expected type. But this complexity isn't really worth it, IMO. Overloading has many corner cases, this is but another.

But there is a trick you can use in this case, if you really need an overload that accepts a single parameter:

```
object Util {
  class Tapper[A](tapMe: A) {
    def tap(f: A => Unit): A = {
      f(tapMe)
      tapMe
    }

    def tap(f0: A => Unit, f1: A => Unit, fs: (A => Unit)*): A = {
      (Seq(f0, f1) ++ fs).foreach(_(tapMe))
      tapMe
    }
  }

  implicit def tapper[A](toTap: A): Tapper[A] = new Tapper(toTap)

  "".tap(_.toString)
  "".tap(_.toString, _.toString)
  "".tap(_.toString, _.toString, _.toString)
}
```

Comment: Excellent idea, thanks! I thought I would have to name them differently.

Comment: You're quickly becoming the new Daniel, Jason!

Comment: @oxbow Even better, he often quotes the spec, which is a good thing.

Comment: If only the spec had a SO account. He knows all the answers!