# Scala can't overload two methods

Tags: scala, jvm, overloading

When I compile code below, the compilator throw error:

> Error:(6, 7) in trait Container, multiple overloaded alternatives of
>   method register define default arguments.

```
def register[A, B <: A](sygnature: Class[A], target: Class[B], lifeTime: LifeTime = Transistent): Unit
  def register[A, B <: A](sygnature: Class[A], inject: () => B, lifeTime: LifeTime = Transistent): Unit
```

I see methods with parameters (Class[A], Class[B], LifeTime) and (Class[A], Function[B], LifeTime)

I don't understand why compilator lose

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4652095/1804173) helps.

Comment: When I remove default values everythink is ok. So I hope in the next releases of Scala it will be fixed.