# Scala: multiple overloaded alternatives of method

Tags: scala

I have this code:

```
case class Sorting(field: String = "createdAt", order: 
 SortingOrder = SortingOrder.Desc)

object Sorting {
  sealed trait SortingOrder

  object SortingOrder {
    case object Desc extends SortingOrder
    case object Asc extends SortingOrder
  }

  def apply(field: Option[String], order: Option[SortingOrder], defaultSortField: String = "createdAt"): Sorting =
    Sorting(
      field.getOrElse(defaultSortField),
      order.getOrElse(SortingOrder.Desc)
    )

}
```

This gives error:

```
in object Sorting, multiple overloaded alternatives of method apply define default arguments.
```

Why am I missing here?

Comment: Well without seeing the code of `Sorting` it is impossible to help.

Comment: I have added full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala compiler will generate default `apply` method in the [companion object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/case-classes.html) which will use your case class constructor parameters i.e. `case class Sorting(field: String = "createdAt", order: SortingOrder = SortingOrder.Desc)` which has default values. And then you have declared another `apply` method which has default parameters also and Scala disallows to have [overloaded methods with default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652095/why-does-the-scala-compiler-disallow-overloaded-methods-with-default-arguments).

So you need to remove default parameter either from case class ([compiles](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hwzopyrWRySMilnF5xVOqw)) or from your custom apply method ([compiles also](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BVWGadNbQSG0N8s9U0PYTg)) or handle custom default case manually by creating extra `apply` overload ([compiles](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WlsbKIpHSdKbWbicTVbPeg)):

```scala
case class Sorting(field: String = "createdAt", order: SortingOrder = SortingOrder.Desc)

object Sorting {
  sealed trait SortingOrder

  object SortingOrder {
    case object Desc extends SortingOrder
    case object Asc extends SortingOrder
  }

  def apply(field: Option[String], order: Option[SortingOrder]): Sorting = apply(field, order, "createdAt")
  def apply(field: Option[String], order: Option[SortingOrder], defaultSortField: String): Sorting =
    Sorting(
      field.getOrElse(defaultSortField),
      order.getOrElse(SortingOrder.Desc)
    )
}
```