# Multiple overloaded alternatives of method apply define default arguments

Tags: scala, default-arguments

I have the following case class

```scala
case class Task[I, O](
    dd: DD,
    parser: CP[I, (O, Option[CE])],
    canonicalize: Boolean,
    opt: Boolean,
    schema: Schema,
    remove: Boolean = false,
    deduplicate: Boolean = false,
    taskId: Option[String] = None
)(implicit
    val ul: UL[O],
    val ael: AEL[O],
    val it: IT[I],
    val ot: TT[O]
)

object Task {
  def apply(
      dd: DD,
      sources: Sources,
      cc: String,
      tc: Option[TC] = None
  )(implicit
      context: PEC
  )
}
```

and I am getting

```
multiple overloaded alternatives of method `apply` define default arguments
```

Obviously, I do not have multiple apply methods here. There's one explicitly defined apply method and another one that is implicitly defined because of the case class. I have to mention that if I remove `tc: Option[TC] = None` from the `apply` method in the companion object, the compilation succeeds. I understand the explanation provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138519/6566916) but I do not see how `tc: Option[TC] = None` is breaking the compilation.

// Edit

Being more explicit about what the compiler generates. For the implicit apply method generated from the case class we will have

```
apply$default$6:Boolean = false
apply$default$7:Boolean = false
apply$default$8:Option[String] = None
```

for the explicit `apply` that I defined it will only create

```
apply$default$4:Option[TC] = None
```

At least this is how I understand it. Where is the clash exactly?

Comment: The simplest solution is to rename the second `apply` to something like `fromSources`

Comment: I think you already got the reason: you cannot have multiple overloaded alternatives with default arguments _including_ those which are generated by the compiler.

Comment: O the bytecode (and Tasty) level it is irrelevant that it wasn't you who defined this `apply`, there are still 2 of them.

Comment: I do not believe that this explains it. Adding a default value for `tc:Option[TC] = None` breaks the compilation. This argument is on position 4 of the explicitly defined apply method. There's no parameter with default value on position 4 on the case class.

Comment: I think the problem is that Scala does not allow to have ANY alternative apply method with default argument. This produces the same issue

```Scala
class Foo(a: String, b: String) {
  def apply(c: Int = 3) = new Foo(c.toString, c.toString)
  def apply(d: Int, e: Int = 100) = new Foo(d.toString, e.toString)
}
```

Comment: Yes, the _any_ was implied. :-)

Comment: The answer I included mentioned the position of the arguments as well and that got me confused.

Answer (score 1):

Scala does not allow the existence of default values in multiple overloaded methods. **The position or the data type of the default value does not matter**. The fact that one of the methods could be an `apply` method does not matter either.

This will work

```
class Foo(a: String, b: String) {
  def apply(c: Int = 3) = new Foo(c.toString, c.toString)

  def other(a: Int = 1, b: String) = println(a, b)
}
```

This will not work

```
class Foo(a: String, b: String) {
  def apply(c: Int = 3) = new Foo(c.toString, c.toString)

  def other(a: Int = 1, b: String) = println(a, b)
  def other(a: Int, b: String = "foo", c: Float) = println(a, b, c)
}
```

This will not work

```
class Foo(a: String, b: String) {
  def apply(c: Int = 3) = new Foo(c.toString, c.toString)
  def apply(d: Int, e: Int = 100) = new Foo(d.toString, e.toString)

  def other(a: Int, b: String = "foo", c: Float) = println(a, b, c)
}
```