# How can I eliminate a parameter from constructor in a subclass in Scala

Tags: scala, constructor

I have a base class named `named` like the following. Its primary constructor takes 4 parameters, `flow1` and `flow2` are of type `T0` and `T1`, which are derived from `Flow`, an abstract class. The `predicate` parameter is a object of `FlowParser`, for different `EitherFlow`, there can be different `FlowParser`.

Now I want to remove in subclasses.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect._


abstract class Flow() extends Serializable {

}

trait FlowParser extends Serializable {
  def judgeIndex(path: String): Int
  def createFlow(path: String): Flow
}

class EitherFlow[T0 >: Null <: Flow: ClassTag, T1 >: Null <: Flow: ClassTag](
    predicate: FlowParser,
    var flow1: T0,
    var flow2: T1,
    var path: String) extends Flow{

  def this(predi: FlowParser, path: String) = this(predi, null, null, path)

  def this(predi: FlowParser) = this(predi, "")

  protected def this(predi: FlowParser, index: Int, d: Flow) {
    this(predi, null, null, "")
    if (index == 0) {
      this.flow1 = d.asInstanceOf[T0]
    } else {
      this.flow2 = d.asInstanceOf[T1]
    }
  }

  def this(predi: FlowParser, d: Flow) {
    this(predi, null, null, "")
    d match {
      case _: T0 => this.flow1 = d.asInstanceOf[T0]
      case _: T1 => this.flow2 = d.asInstanceOf[T1]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have many subclasses from `EitherFlow`, such as `EitherFlow[DataFrameFlow, RawFlow]`. So I may write code like this

```
new EitherFlow[DataFrameFlow, RawFlow](new MyAnnoyingFlowParser(), "")
```

However, `new MyAnnoyingFlowParser()` is not necessary, because given `T0` and `T1` are certain, the type of `MyAnnoyingFlowParser` is certain, so actually I want this:

```
new EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow("")
```

UPDATE:

There are many constructors in `EitherFlow`, I want to do the following

```
// original
new EitherFlow[DataFrameFlow, RawFlow](new MyAnnoyingFlowParser(), a, b, c, ...)
// what I want
new EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow(a, b, c, ...)
```

I have tried the following strategies, and I meet some problems in both of them.

1. Try "currying" the `apply` method
   With this strategy, I want I can write this

   ```
   val f1 = EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow("")
   val f2 = EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow(new RawFlow(), "")
   ```

   So I decide to write the following code, it actually returns a anonymous Object, which has overloaded `apply` method. I adopt this strategy from this post([Scala, currying and overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179229/scala-currying-and-overloading))

   ```
   object EitherFlow {
     def apply[T0 >: Null <: Flow: ClassTag, T1 >: Null <: Flow: ClassTag](predicate: FlowParser) =
       new {
         def apply[R >: Null <: Flow: ClassTag](flow: R, path: String): EitherFlow[T0, T1] = {
           val ret = new EitherFlow[T0, T1](predicate, flow)
           ret.path = path
           ret
         }
         def apply(path: String): EitherFlow[T0, T1] = {
           new EitherFlow[T0, T1](predicate, null.asInstanceOf[T0], null.asInstanceOf[T1], path)
         }
       }
   }
   ```

   However, with this strategy, I have to use `.apply` explicitly. Or, it will cause an error

   ```
   com.xxx.flow.EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow.type does not take parameters
   ```
2. Try create a new class and implement its own aux constructors

   However, I am confused when I try to implememt aux constructor `def this(d: Flow)`.
   According to [alexander](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-class-superclass-constructor-in-scala-parent-class/), I can't directly call super's aux constructor. So I have to write like the following

   ```
   class EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow(var f1: DataFrameFlow, var f2: RawFlow, path: String) extends EitherFlow[DataFrameFlow, RawFlow](new DataFrameRawFlowParser(), f1, f2, path) {
     def this(d: Flow) {
       this(null, null, "")
       d match {
         case _: DataFrameFlow => this.flow1 = d.asInstanceOf[DataFrameFlow]
         case _: RawFlow => this.flow2 = d.asInstanceOf[RawFlow]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   However, I think the code is not neat. Firstly, I have to write duplicate code such as `d match {...}`. Second, I have to define duplicate parameters suchas `f1`/`f2`.

Comment: Your code you've started with doesn't compile with `not enough arguments for constructor Flow`: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MzEiQW61Ta6ui56LzSSpyA If I comment out `(var outputName: String)` it doesn't compile with `ambiguous implicit values`: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qeA70jcER4qj43CUYCe30A . Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @DmytroMitin , I have [my codes edited](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pfkkMR3PTViqGwSTJYFglg), and I use Scala 2.11.8, which can compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, it *seems* there would be only one correct implementation for `DataFlowParser`. Making that implicit is then the logical route. But we can't see that far into your design and constraints.

Given the constraints

- flow1 and flow2 are both `var`'s, both or neither can be null, both have an available classtag that adequately identifies the values in the face of erasure (so they don't have a type parameter)
- you want to be able to call `EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow(fl: Flow)` and return a value of type `EitherFlow[DataFrameFlow, RawFlow]`

I'd just make

```
object EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow {
  def apply(fl: Flow) = new EitherFlow[DataFrameFlow, RawFlow](new MyAnnoyingFlowParser(), fl)
}
```

and not make a subclass at all.

I'm not clear on whether you pass a new `MyAnnoyingFlowParser` or a new `DataFrameRawFlowParser`, but you can switch that out yourself.

Edit: you can make a base class for the objects too:

```
abstract class PartiallyAppliedEitherConstructor[Flow1, Flow2](parser: => FlowParser) {
  def apply(fl: Flow) = new EitherFlow[Flow1, Flow2](parser)
  def apply(index: Int, flow: Flow) = new EitherFlow[Flow1, Flow2)(parser, index, flow)
  //etc
}

object EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow extends PartiallyAppliedEitherConstructor[DataframeFlow, RawFlow](new MyAnnoyingFlowParser())

object EitherRddOrDataFrameFlow extends PartiallyAppliedEitherConstructor[RddFlow, DataFromeFlow](new SomeOtherFlowParser())

//etc
```

Comment: Hi Martjin, it is not true that "it seems there would be only one correct implementation for DataFlowParser". For `EitherFlow[DataFrameFlow, RawFlow]` I can have `EitherDataFrameOrRawFlow`, However, there will be other `EitherFlow`s, such as `EitherFlow[DataFrameFlow, RDDFlow]`, so there will be multiple subclass which inherits `FlowParser`

Comment: And I have considered your solution, it is practical, however, for every subclass of `EitherFlow`, I have to implement multiple overloads of `apply`, which simply forwards some of its arguments(except the first `FlowParser` argument), I think it results in lots of redundant code.

Comment: @calvin multiple apply methods for the specialized type wasn't part of your original question. Can you concisely indicate what exactly your design constraints are and what must by implemented?

Comment: You said "so they don't have a type parameter", however, I think if `T0` and `T1` are not visible in runtime, should the compiler warns "is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure" or something? However, I have seen no such warnings. And I don't know if there is any side effect if "don't have a type parameter", because pattern matching still works here?

Comment: Multiple apply methods for the specialized type is not in my question, because I already find [a solution to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179229/scala-currying-and-overloading) when I try the first strategy 1. However, there are other problems about strategy 1

Comment: @calvin you only have a classtag, so you can't match on parameterized types. e.g. you can't see the difference between `T0 = MyFlow[Int]` and `T0 = MyFlow[String]`. But leaving that aside, what are the apply methods/constructors you need exactly for what parameters and with what return types?

Comment: So I need a TypeTag?

Comment: Hi Martijn, Could you answer my prev question?

Comment: @calvin if you need to check whether some value has some specific type, where the type, you need a TypeTag, yes