# Double Definition Error Despite Different Parameter Types

Tags: scala, types, compiler-errors, overloading

I'm receiving a double definition error on the following two methods:

```
def apply[T](state: T, onRender: T => Graphic,
             onMouseEvent: (MouseEvent, T) => T): GraphicPanel = 
  apply(state, onRender, onMouseEvent = Some(onMouseEvent))
```

and

```
def apply[T](state: T, onRender: T => Graphic,
             onKeyEvent: (KeyEvent, T) => T): GraphicPanel = 
  apply(state, onRender, onKeyEvent = Some(onKeyEvent))
```

which are both method overloads for the more general `apply` method with the signature:

```
def apply[T](state: T, onRender: T => Graphic,
             onTickEvent: Option[T => T] = None, fps: Int = 30,
             onMouseEvent: Option[(MouseEvent, T) => T] = None,
             onMouseMotionEvent: Option[(MouseEvent, T) => T] = None,
             onMouseInputEvent: Option[(MouseEvent, T) => T] = None,
             onKeyEvent: Option[(KeyEvent, T) => T] = None)
```

I would assume that a even though the classes `KeyEvent` and `MouseEvent` have a common superclass (`InputEvent`), the compiler should still be able to distinguish between them.  However, it is throwing the error:

> double definition: method apply:[T](state: T, onRender: T =>
>   edu.depauw.scales.graphics.Graphic, someOnKeyEvent:
>   (java.awt.event.KeyEvent, T) =>
>   T)edu.depauw.scales.graphics.GraphicPanel and method apply:[T](state:
>   T, onRender: T => edu.depauw.scales.graphics.Graphic, onMouseEvent:
>   (java.awt.event.MouseEvent, T) =>
>   T)edu.depauw.scales.graphics.GraphicPanel at line 115 have same type
>   after erasure: (state: Object, onRender: Function1, someOnKeyEvent:
>   Function2) edu.depauw.scales.graphics.GraphicPanel

Anyone have any idea what is going on? Admittedly, I don't know what is meant by the phrase *"after erasure"*, so maybe an explanation of how that works might be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simpler example that shows the same issue:

```
object Example {
  def foo[T](f: Int => T) = ???
  def foo[T](f: String => T) = ???
}
```

This is equivalent to the following, after desugaring the `=>` symbols:

```
object Example {
  def foo[T](f: Function[Int, T]) = ???
  def foo[T](f: Function[String, T]) = ???
}
```

The problem is that the Java Virtual Machine [doesn't know about generics](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/12/scala-and-erasure/) (in either Scala or Java), so it sees these two methods as the following:

```
object Example {
  def foo[T](f: Function) = ???
  def foo[T](f: Function) = ???
}
```

Which is clearly a problem.

This is one of [many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2512001/334519) to avoid method overloading in Scala. If that's not an option, you could use a trick like the following:

```
object Example {
  implicit object `Int => T disambiguator`
  implicit object `String => T disambiguator`

  def foo[T](f: Int => T)(implicit d: `Int => T disambiguator`.type) = ???
  def foo[T](f: String => T)(implicit d: `String => T disambiguator`.type) = ???
}
```

Which looks the same usage-wise, but is obviously pretty hideous.

Comment: Naming your object `\`Int => T disambiguator\`` does not help the degree of hideousness (even if it is valuable for pedagogy) :)

Comment: I guess I like my ugly hacks to be ugly all the way through!