# Overloaded method value with alternatives

Tags: scala, overloading

I have the following:

```
def calc(dir: File): Option[Group] = {
 calcModel(dir) match {
  case Some(model: Model) => calcUI(model, centerpane.getWidth, centerpane.getHeight, 5, MAX_LEVEL)
  case None =>               None
 }
}

def calcUI(model: Model, availableWidth: Double, availableHeight: Double, maxLevel: Int): Option[Group] = {
}

def calcUI(model: Model, posX: Double, posY: Double, availableWidth: Double, availableHeight: Double, horizontally: Boolean, startLevel: Int, maxLevel: Int): Option[Group] = {
}

protected def calcUI(node: Node, posX: Double, posY: Double, availableWidth: Double, availableHeight: Double, horizontally: Boolean, level: Int, maxLevel: Int): Group = {
}

def calcModel(dir: File): Option[Model] = {
}
```

(Remark: Model does NOT derive from Node)

and get the following compiler error message:

```
Error:(88, 27) overloaded method value calcUI with alternatives:
  (node: org.rob.spaceview.modell.Node,posX: Double,posY: Double,availableWidth: Double,availableHeight: Double,horizontally: Boolean,level: Int,maxLevel: Int)javafx.scene.Group <and>
  (model: org.rob.spaceview.modell.Model,posX: Double,posY: Double,availableWidth: Double,availableHeight: Double,horizontally: Boolean,startLevel: Int,maxLevel: Int)Option[javafx.scene.Group] <and>
  (model: org.rob.spaceview.modell.Model,availableWidth: Double,availableHeight: Double,maxLevel: Int)Option[javafx.scene.Group]
 cannot be applied to (org.rob.spaceview.modell.Model, Double, Double, Int, Int)
      case Some(model) => calcUI(model, centerpane.getWidth, centerpane.getHeight, 5, MAX_LEVEL)
                      ^
```

I do not get it. All calcUI functions are different by parameters.

I know this error and most of the time I get it and fix it. But here, no clue.

Hopefully somebody enlights me. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it, either. Which method do you expect to select?  You use five args.  You know overloads are evil, right? At least, unless you know what you're doing?

Comment: Overloads are evil? I would say overloading is an extremely useful and important aspect of Java/Scala.

Comment: See the answer and my comment below. Shame on me.

Comment: @Keppil  E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2510108/1296806 or google it. Also, I can't reply if you don't use @. Even if it is a necessary evil (debatable), still evil.

Comment: @som: Interesting link, thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, the given parameters in the call

```
case Some(model) => calcUI(model, centerpane.getWidth, centerpane.getHeight, 5, MAX_LEVEL)
```

don't correspond to any defined `calcUI` method. For example for the following definition

```
def calcUI(model: Model, availableWidth: Double, availableHeight: Double, maxLevel: Int): Option[Group]
```

you have one more argument than needed.

Comment: Oh my god, that is extremly embarrassing. You are right, the most clear obvious problem I did not see. Shame on me. Thanks for counting right for me...

Comment: Embarrassing, but also a useful data point on why overloading is best avoided.  Even for obvious cases, people wind up confused.

Comment: It can happen to the best of us. And I kind of agree with @som-snytt about overloading. You can accept the answer to mark the question resolved.

Comment: This is a great answer because I faced the same issue and only counted after reading the answer!