# In scala, what is the easiest way to "flatten" a product type?

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types

I'm investigating the compatibility of scala language and matured algebraic type system, here is an interesting case:

Assuming I have a complex type CC that is the product of AA and BB:

```
case class AA(_1: Int, _2: Int)
case class BB(_3: Int)
case class CC(a: AA, b: BB)
```

now I want to define a type algebra flatten(.), which can flatten all internal product types in the definition of its operand, e.g. flatten(CC) can yield the following product type definition:

```
case class FCC(_1: Int, _2: Int, _3: Int)
```

How hard is it to implement something like this in scala 2.12+? You are welcomed to use whatever trick possible, including but not limited to: Macro, scalaz, cats, shapeless, etc.

Thanks a lot for your opinion!

Comment: I am pretty sure this is _doable_ with **Shapeless**.

Comment: Would you mind divulging some details?

Comment: Sorry, haven't used it. But I know this is the kind of things **shapeless** solves. You may try reading the _"type astronaut guide to shapeless"_.  Note, that all types should exists. If you want to create new types, you should use macros.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with `shapeless` but not trivial. Here is an incomplete sketch which most probably will have to be tweaked.

Declare the desired interface. We'll flatten the tree into `HList`

```
import shapeless._

trait Flattener[A] {
   type Result <: HList

   def flatten(input: A): Result
}

object Flattener {
  type Aux[T, R] = Flattener[T] { type Result = R }
}

def flatten[A](input: A)(implicit ev: Flattener[A]): ev.Result = {
  ev.flatten(input)
}
```

Now we have 3 cases: `A` is either a non-product type and will be marshalled directly into a single-element list:

```
implicit def nonProdFlattener[T : NotAProduct] : Flattener.Aux[T, (T :: HNil)] = {
  new Flattener[T] {
    override type Result = (T :: HNil)

    override def flatten(input: T) = HList(input)
  }
}
```

Here we need a proof that `T` is not a product itself. `shapeless` doesn't have it out of the box (AFAIK) but you can use this trick: [Scala: Enforcing A is not a subtype of B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103126/scala-enforcing-a-is-not-a-subtype-of-b?noredirect=1)

Second case: `P` is a one-element product of type `T` and we already know how to convert `T` into `R`

```
implicit def oneElementProduct[T, R, P <: Product](implicit ev: Aux[P, T :: HNil], fl: Flattener.Aux[T, R]): Flattener.Aux[T, R] = ???
```

And the last case: `P` is a product starting with `H` and continues with `T` (which is `HList`)

```
implicit def multiElemProduct[P, R1, R2, H, T](implicit ev: Aux[P, H :: T], fl1: Flattener.Aux[H, R1], fl2: Flattener.Aux[T, R2]):
  Flattener.Aux[P, R1 :: R2] = ???
```

Then if you want to convert to a predefined `FCC` instead of `HList` you'll need `Generic` (https://www.scala-exercises.org/shapeless/generic) to convert `HList` to a case-class.