# Covariance between 3 types in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, covariance, union-types

I'm trying to see if there is a way to find a type `W2` that is the super type of 2 types `W` and `E`.
In my solution `E` represents errors, and `W` represents Warnings.
What I'm trying to accomplish is a method `or` that if `this` fails runs `that` and moves the error to the warning type.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm doing.

```
sealed trait Validator[-I, +E, +W, +A] extends Product with Serializable
```

this type has several cases, which aren't really important here, so instead I'll go over an example usage:

```
case class MyObj(coords: GeoCoords)
case class GeoCoords(lat: String, long: String)
        
// Getters
val getLatitude: Validator[GeoCoords, Nothing, Nothing, String] = from[GeoCoords].map(_.lat)
val getLongitude: Validator[GeoCoords, Nothing, Nothing, String] = from[GeoCoords].map(_.long)

val parseLatitude: Validator[GeoCoords, Exception, Nothing, Double] = getLatitude andThen nonEmptyString andThen convertToDouble
val parseLongitude: Validator[GeoCoords, Exception, Nothing, Double] = getLongitude andThen convertToDouble
```

Now this is a bad example, but what I'm looking to do is that because `parseLatitude` has an error type of `Exception`, perhaps I want to give a default instead, but still understand that it failed.  I'd like to move the `Exception` from the `E` error param to the `W` warning param like this:

```
val defaultLatitude: Validator[GeoCoords, Nothing, Nothing, Double] = success(0)

val finalLatitude: Validator[GeoCoords, Nothing, Exception, Double] = parseLatitude or defaultLatitude
```

But as well, if instead of supplying default, the other action I take after the `or` may fail as well, therefore this should also be the case:

```
val otherAction: Validator[GeoCoords, Throwable, Nothing, Double] = ???

val finalLatitude: Validator[GeoCoords, Throwable, Exception, Double] = parseLatitude or otherAction
```

I've tried implementing `or` in several ways on the `Validator` type but everytime it gives me an issue, basically casting things all the way up to `Any`.

```
def or[I2 <: I, E2 >: E, W2 >: W, B >: A](that: Validator[I2, E2, W2, B]): Validator[I2, E2, W2, B] = Validator.conversion { (i: I2) =>
  val aVal: Validator[Any, E, W, A] = this.run(i)
  val bVal: Validator[Any, E2, W2, B] = that.run(i)

  val a: Vector[W2] = aVal.warnings ++ bVal.warnings
  // PROBLEM HERE
  val b: Vector[Any] = a ++ aVal.errors

  Result(
    aVal.warnings ++ aVal.errors ++ bVal.warnings,
    bVal.value.toRight(bVal.errors)
  )
}
```

I need to be able to say that `W2` is both a supertype of `W` and of `E` so that I can concatenate the `Vector`s together and get type `W2` at the end.

A super simplified self contained example is:

```
case class Example[+A, +B](a: List[A], b: List[B]) {
  def or[A2 >: A, B2 >: B](that: Example[A2, B2]): Example[A2, Any] = {
    Example(that.a, this.a ++ this.b ++ that.a)
  }
}

object stackoverflow extends App {

  val example1 = Example(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
  val example2 = Example(List(5, 6), List(7, 8))

  val example3 = example1 or example2

}
```

Where I want the output type of `or` to be `Example[A2, B2]` instead of `Example[A2, Any]`

Comment: Does it really make sense to upcast both warnings and errors into the same type? How do you differentiate them latter? Why not just using something like `List[Either[Warning, Error]]`? or your own `WarningOrError` **ADT**?

Comment: that's a thought actually.  I may do that.  I would still like to know if there is an answer to how to do it though, as it has become more of a curiosity to me :)

Comment: @NigelBenns Please prepare [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (you didn't provide definitions of `Validator`, `Result` etc.). Also please specify what's wrong with 3 code snippets you wrote (how do you apply `or`, how did you check that *"Scala resolves the `W2` as `Any`"*). *"I'm trying to see if there is a way to find a type `W2` that is the super type of 2 types `W` and `E`"* Would you please make it clear what you are trying to achieve? `Any` is a supertype of arbitrary `W` and `E`. What is "**the** supertype"?

Comment: Question updated with a usecase.  If need be I can try to simplify things down to just those types and provide a full working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you want the concatenation of a `List[A]` and a `List[B]` to produce a `List[A | B]`, where `A | B` is [union type](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html).

[How to define "type disjunction" (union types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types)

In Scala 2 union types are absent but we can emulate them with type classes.

So regarding "super simplified example" try a type class `LUB` (least upper bound)

```
case class Example[A, B](a: List[A], b: List[B]) {
  def or[A2 >: A, B2, AB](that: Example[A2, B2])(
    implicit
    lub: LUB.Aux[A, B, AB],
    lub1: LUB[AB, A2]
  ): Example[A2, lub1.Out] = {
    Example(that.a, (this.a.map(lub.coerce1) ++ this.b.map(lub.coerce2)).map(lub1.coerce1(_)) ++ that.a.map(lub1.coerce2(_)))
  }
}

val example1: Example[Int, Int] = Example(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
val example2: Example[Int, Int] = Example(List(5, 6), List(7, 8))

val example3 = example1 or example2
//  example3: Example[Int, Any] // doesn't compile
example3: Example[Int, Int] // compiles

trait LUB[A, B] {
  type Out
  def coerce1(a: A): Out
  def coerce2(b: B): Out
}

trait LowPriorityLUB {
  type Aux[A, B, Out0] = LUB[A, B] { type Out = Out0 }
  def instance[A, B, Out0](f: (A => Out0, B => Out0)): Aux[A, B, Out0] = new LUB[A, B] {
    override type Out = Out0
    override def coerce1(a: A): Out0 = f._1(a)
    override def coerce2(b: B): Out0 = f._2(b)
  }

  implicit def bSubtypeA[A, B <: A]: Aux[A, B, A] = instance(identity, identity)
}

object LUB extends LowPriorityLUB {
  implicit def aSubtypeB[A <: B, B]: Aux[A, B, B] = instance(identity, identity)
  implicit def default[A, B](implicit ev: A <:!< B, ev1: B <:!< A): Aux[A, B, Any] = 
    instance(identity, identity)
}

// Testing:
implicitly[LUB.Aux[Int, AnyVal, AnyVal]]
implicitly[LUB.Aux[AnyVal, Int, AnyVal]]
implicitly[LUB.Aux[Int, String, Any]]
implicitly[LUB.Aux[Int, Int, Int]]
//  implicitly[LUB.Aux[Int, AnyVal, Any]] // doesn't compile
```

`<:!<` is from here:

[Scala: Enforcing A is not a subtype of B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103126/scala-enforcing-a-is-not-a-subtype-of-b)

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/package.scala#L48-L52

If you want `Example` to be covariant

```
case class Example[+A, +B]...
```

make `LUB` and `LUB.Aux` contravariant

```
trait LUB[-A, -B]...

type Aux[-A, -B, Out0] = LUB[A, B] { type Out = Out0 }
```

Comment: I had to use Shapless' Lub instead of the one there, it was still giving me `Any`.  However once switching to that it worked fine.  Thanks!

Comment: @NigelBenns Well, honestly I forgot that there was `shapeless.Lub` :) Actually, for me `shapeless.Lub` seems to work https://scastie.scala-lang.org/F0pWNaYSStyTEwWMKqHLpA