# Implicitly convert parameter Option[T] to T in a case class

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I had a case class with a option parameter, let's say:

```
case class Student(id: Option[Int], name: String)
```

To get a Student instance, not only I could use `Student(Some(1), "anderson")`, I also want this form to be a valid way `Student(2,"Sarah")`

I guess I have to create a `Int => Option[Int]` and put it somewhere. So what's the best way to do so?

**Update**

As mentioned in the comment, override `apply` method will block calling it by `Student.apply _`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be easier to just make an `apply` method in a companion `object`.

```
case class Student(id: Option[Int], name: String)

object Student {
  def apply(id: Int, name: String): Student = {
    Student(Some(id), name)
  }
}
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest naming this method something other than `apply`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Why? Isn't the point of this to be able to use it the same as the auto-generated `apply` method? Unless it's named `apply`, he can't use `Student(2, "Sarah")`.

Comment: @resueman There are [lots of reasons to avoid overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2512001/334519). One additional one off the top of my head for this case specifically: it would break Play's automatic JSON codec generation (and presumably similar mechanisms in other projects).

Comment: Thanks @Brian, it is a convenient way indeed! And thanks to Travis for further information!

Comment: I totally agree with @TravisBrown when he says: "it would break Play's automatic JSON codec generation (and presumably similar mechanisms in other projects)". I can hear you there and, in that case, you don't get the clearest error message ever, to use an understatement.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using implicit conversions:

```
implicit def intToOption(x: Int) = Some(x)
case class Student(id: Option[Int], name: String)

scala> Student(1,"Nu")
res1: Student = Student(Some(1),Nu)
```

Comment: I am aware of this approach. But it requires bringing the implicit conversion in to the scope where you try to construct the case class this way, which can be very tedious. Is there a technic to cut the "import" effort?

Comment: Please don't do this—implicit conversions are almost always a terrible idea, and the terribleness is proportional to how often you use values of the types involved, so an implicit conversion from `Int` to anything is just bad news.

Comment: Still deciding on implicit myself. As always, power comes with responsibility. If you are doing this for production level code, you might have to go with some more "safe" solution. If you are doing this for your own project, then I feel it's cool enough to deserve a chance.