# Scala overload function to add currying?

Tags: scala, currying

Started learning Scala today, and I was curious if you can overload a function to add currying like:

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
def add(x: Int)(y: Int): Int = x + y
```

But not only does this code not compile, but I've heard that overloading in Scala is not a good idea.

Is there a way to overload add such that it's curried without doing partial application, meaning both `add(1, 2)` and `add(1)(2)` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that those `add` functions are indistinguishable after JVM type erasure: during execution they are both `(Int, Int)Int`. But they are different during compilation, and Scala compiler can tell which one you are calling.

This means you have to make their argument lists different. To achieve that you can add an implicit argument list with a `DummyImplicit` argument:

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int)(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit): Int = x + y
def add(x: Int)(y: Int): Int = x + y
```

This `DummyImplicit` is provided by Scala library, and there is always an implicit value for it. Now the first function after erasure has a type `(Int, Int, DummyImplicit)Int`, and the second one `(Int, Int)Int`, so JVM can distinguish them.

Now you can call both:

```
add(1, 2)
add(1)(2)
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, but a little too hacky I think to ever be practical. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For overloading it's necessary that function should either:

- have different number of arguments
- or have different argument type(s)

In your example both definitions of `add` are equivalent hence it's not overloading and you get compilation error.

You could use Kolmar's way (`implicit` object) below to call both `add(1, 2)` and `add(1)(2)` OR you can use Scala's [Default Parameter](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/default-parameter-values.html) to achieve same thing:

```
def add(a: Int, b: Int, c: Any = DummyImplicit) = a + b // c is default parameter
def add(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b
```

About:

> I've heard that overloading in Scala is not a good idea.

You can see [Why "avoid method overloading"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510108/why-avoid-method-overloading)

Comment: How can I achieve what I'm proposing though? So I can call add(1, 2) and add(1)(2).

Comment: Sorry about the edit, I'm afraid if there is a way that you can use both `add(1, 2)` and `add(1)(2)`.

Comment: Ah ok no worries. I was just curious if it was possible. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a way you can use add(1,2) and add(1)(2) but I wouldn't recommend it. It uses Scala's implicit definitions to have a different type for both methods, but use an implicit method to convert to the appropriate type.

```
case class IntWrapper(value: Int) // Purely to have a different type

object CurryingThing
{
  def add(x: IntWrapper)(y: IntWrapper) = x.value + y.value
  def add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y

  // The magic happens here. In the event that you have an int, but the function requires an intWrapper (our first function definition), Scala will invoke this implicit method to convert it
  implicit def toWrapper(x: Int) = IntWrapper(x)

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
   // Now you can use both add(1,2) and add(1)(2) and the appropriate function is called
   println(add(1,2)) //Compiles, prints 3
   println(add(1)(2)) // Compiles, prints 3
   ()
  }
}
```